# Getting a list of previously connected BLE devices in react native

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hi I'm writing a mobile app that has to get access to the list of BLE devices the device has previously connected to. I've searched into BLE libraries but to my understanding (I'm a total beginner) you can scan for available or currently connected devices. Is there a way to get the list of all recorded devices regardless of their connection state?
I tried looking at the docs of the main react-native libraries for BLE management like react-native-plx and react-native-ble-manager but all I could find is methods to get the devices advertising or connected when you make the request
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get the list of all recorded devices regardless of their connection state?

No. This is not available to iOS applications. It doesn't matter if you use React Native or something else. You can discuss your goal (what does the user want that you are using this to deliver), and there may be another way to achieve it. Or you can send your use case as a [Feedback](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com), but I doubt it would be added unless you have an incredibly valuable use case. (It could too easily be used to fingerprint users, which Apple intends to prevent.)

Comment: OK, thanks for the help. Basically I needed a list of the saved device to generate a notification when one of these (user selected) connected or disconnected. I guess I will do it when the actual connection takes place...thank you again!

Comment: yeah; in order to detect when the device connects, you'll need its Peripheral ID, and you can only get that while it's connected. But once you have it, you'll be able to run a long-running `connect` request that will launch your app if the device comes into range. You can also get a notification when the device disconnects, though having used this to build a "find my device" feature, it's not always as reliable as you'd want it to be. (Even Apple has some trouble with this for the Find My feature for Beats earbuds, which made me feel a bit better about my difficulties...)